Hover:Scale not working for tailwind-rails? Any suggestions?
This is my code and I want to apply the hover:Scale utility from tailwindCSS to my link boxes but it's not working. Any idea what conflicts I'm creating here?
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<% end %>

<h1 class="mb-6 font-bold text-6xl">Contacts Dashboard</h1>

<%= link_to 'Export to CSV', export_admin_contact_dashboard_index_path(format: :csv), class: 'text-white ease-in-out bg-green-500 hover:no-underline hover:bg-green-600 hover:scale-90 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg' %>. 
<!-- This is the box I've been testing the hover scale on and it's' not working. -->

<%= link_to 'Export to PDF', export_admin_contact_dashboard_index_path(format: :pdf), class: 'text-white bg-red-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-red-700 active:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-400 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-xl' %>

<%= link_to 'Export to Excel', export_admin_contact_dashboard_index_path(format: :xlsx), class: 'text-white bg-green-800 hover:no-underline hover:bg-green-700 active:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-green-400 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg ' %>

I've tried to use vanilla CSS but it isn't working either.

You can't transform an inline element. Make your link a block, inline-block, or flex.

Only transformable elements can be transformed. That is, all elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform
